# compiling qt 4.7.3 on mingw32 with gcc 4.6.0

Tags: qt, gcc, mingw

I am trying to compile Qt 4.7.3 on mignw32 using gcc 4.6.0.
I get the following error when running ./configure:

```
In file included from C:/work/qt-gcc-4.6.0/include/QtCore/private/qcore_unix_p.h:1:0,
                 from C:/work/qt-gcc-4.6.0/src/corelib/io/qfsfileengine_unix.cpp:45:
C:/work/qt-gcc-4.6.0/include/QtCore/private/../../../src/corelib/kernel/qcore_unix_p.h:59:3: error: #error "qcore_unix_p.h included on a non-Unix system"
```

The weird thing is that I am running Windows 7, and it is trying to include that.
Also in the Makefile it is using  qfsfileengine_unix and qfsfileengine_iterator_unix instead of     qfsfileengine_win and qfsfileengine_iterator_win.

If I change the Makefile to use the Windows' ones, I get the following error (the file does not exist):

```
In file included from C:/work/qt-gcc-4.6.0/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:62:0,
                 from C:/work/qt-gcc-4.6.0/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1,
                 from C:/work/qt-gcc-4.6.0/mkspecs/win32-g++/qplatformdefs.h:53,
                 from C:/work/qt-gcc-4.6.0/src/corelib/io/qfsfileengine_win.cpp:43:
C:/work/qt-gcc-4.6.0/include/QtCore/qconfig.h:1:46: fatal error: ../../src/corelib/global/qconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

When compiling /qt/src/corelib/io/qfsfileengine_win.cpp

Suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't wanna just use a binary if you are on windows??

Comment: To develop Qt apps I have to use the gcc that comes with the Qt SDK, which is very old (4.4.0) and lacks C++0x

Answer (score 0):

Try ./configure --help

There is probably a flag for a ms-windows, x86 compilation.

It might be something like:

./configure --target-os=mingw32

Keep in mind -- the os **parameter name** might be different, and the **selectable target values** **might be different** -- with scripts from different authors -- some values you might encounter might be 'win32', 'win32-386', 'x86-windows32', etc.

See if

./configure --help

Won't give you a list...

You can also redirect its output to a file for easy reading in your favorite editor,

./configure --help > myconfighelp.txt

Good luck!